# Leer archivo de configuracion externo distinto a app.config

Tags: c#, xml

lo que trato de hacer es leer un archivo app.config, pero por requerimiento tiene que tener otro nombre llámese badar.config y no estar dentro del mismo proyecto sino digamos en el disco "D" en la misma raíz. Ya he googleado y no he encontrado una respuesta clara a este requerimiento. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Que información quieres guardar en dicho archivo `badar.config`?

Comment: No les facil hacerlo. Lo mejor seria buscar la seccion que deseas leer utilizando `XDocument`.

Comment: Informacion como numeros de puerto, algunas IPs que se van a cambiar, pero no muchas para que no ameriten crear una tabla de ello. Ahora otra duda que me he dado cuenta que cuando genero el .exe y cambio un valor del app.config tengo que volver a generar de nuevo otro .exe para que me capture los nuevos valores que modifique del app.config. Alguna solución ?

Comment: O sea que lo que necesitas parametrizar en dicho archivo `badar.config` son claves de `appSettings`?

Comment: realmente no es muy dificil, lees ese archivo como si fuera un archivo de texto normal, y luego, en cada linea, segun su posicion, ya sabes tu lo que hay, por ejemplo defines que la ip va en la primera linea, el nombre en la segunda, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la propiedad  SectionInformation.ConfigSource
para hacerlo  por código , esta es una buena librería https://github.com/RickStrahl/Westwind.ApplicationConfiguration